# Want to convert my SQL query into django orm query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    form_fields.label_name, 
    entry_details.value, 
    entry_details.entry_id
FROM 
    form_fields 
JOIN 
    entry_details ON entry_details.field_id = form_fields.id 
WHERE 
    form_fields.id IN (21401, 21402) 
    AND entry_details.entry_id = 79;
```

I am a entry level developer having problem to convert this query into django query... Please help me

Comment: Hi, to help you. You should provide your django models and show what you try and when you have an issue

Comment: sure i will provide my django models:- form_fields and entry_details both are models remaining are fields

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `form_fields` model is called `FormFields` and `entry_details` is a field on this model then it should be something like:

```
query = FormFields.objects.filter(
    id__in=[21401, 21402], entry_details__id=79)
    .select_related(
        "entry_details"
        ).only("label_name", "entry_details__id", "entry_details__value")
```

I'm not sure about `only` here. You can try without it first

Comment: `values` is likely better than `only` here.

Comment: @Bartosz Stasiak **entry_details** is also a model